# Why has my VB.net program decided to be case fussy?

Tags: vb.net

I have a small VB.net program that opens some text files, 2 Excel files, a PDF file & creates a new Word document, or opens it if it already exists. Nothing clever, no databases & it works just fine.

I have just bought a Lima device (https://meetlima.com) and have moved my data & program onto the HD attached to it. This is showing on my PC as the "L" drive and everything seems to work EXCEPT the program has now decided to be fussy about the case of the data names !!!

For instance, this code worked just fine before I moved it from my "D" drive to "L" when trying to use the file Tes1 when the value of myLeftCB is TES

```
myRARfile = myFolder + myLeftCB + mySession + ".zip"
```

Now I have had to edit the code to this

```
myRARfile = myFolder + StrConv(myLeftCB, VbStrConv.ProperCase) + mySession + ".zip"
```

The trouble is, there are a number of similar checks & I don't really want to change all of them, if possible I'd just like to know why something has changed, and where, so I can hopefully change it back !!!

Comment: Are you able to browse your _myFolder_ from Windows Explorer? If yes what is the case of the first letter of your file? Are you able to create a new file with the first letter in a different case (in Explorer or with a program)? It seems a file system problem than a program problem. Probably you should ask their support.

Comment: Don't concatenate strings with `+`. Use `&` and turn on `Option Strict`. Even better for a path, use `IO.Path.Combine()` to build the full filename

Comment: I can access all folders, Steve, yes, and I am able to create files with any mixture of cases. I am waiting to hear back from their support ...

Comment: I am taking a look Jens ...

Answer (score 0):

Because Lima is a separate device acting as a file system it's almost certain to be running some form of *nix and that means a case sensitive file system.  In order to map case insensitive Windows filenames onto case-sensitive storage they must be doing some magic, leading to your unexpected results.

I agree with @Steve that you're going to have to seek answers from the vendor documentation for this one.  In particular, examine the technical documentation to see if there are settings that control how case sensitivity is managed.

If you've got a number of places where this code is duplicated then I'd say that you've already got a weak point in your code.  I suggest replacing all of those lines with call to a function that returns the filename.  That's a pain to do but it replaces the code duplication so if you have to change the code in future you're only changing it in one place.  Your code is easier to maintain and when the Lima vendors change their API in two months you'll only have to change the code in one place to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, as I've just said to Steve, I am waiting to hear back from their support but I think it's the early hours of the morning there :-( ...